# Remote File to Variables (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am attempting to create a reader for a certain type of file used by the old Toontown Online. Its a `patcher.ver`. I have tried reading the variables with dictionary from the page it is hosted at, but cannot seem to get it to work!

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(Form1.patcherBaseURL + "/patcher.ver");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
string html = String.Empty;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data))
{
    html = sr.ReadToEnd();
    var dic = File.ReadAllLines(html)
        .Select(l => l.Split(new[] { '=' }))
        .ToDictionary(s => s[0].Trim(), s => s[1].Trim());
    string PatchVerStrServer = dic["PATCHER_VERSION_STRING_SERVER"];
```

This is the code i was attempting to use. However i keep getting exceptions `"illegal characters in path"`

The file i am trying to read is located at: http://dolimg.com/toontown/uk/patcher.ver

Thanks if you can help! I am new to C# and i couldn't seem to find anything related to this.

Comment: Well what is the value of `html`? Is it actually a filename?

Comment: Looking again, presumably `html` is the content of `http://dolimg.com/toontown/uk/patcher.ver`. Now, that's not a filename - do why are you trying to *use* it as a filename? That's what `File.ReadAllLines` does.

Comment: I have it downloading and reading the patcher.ver file with that code to add the variables to the dictionary. The value of html is just the data i get from the patcher.ver file i assume

Comment: Yes, it is. Now look at how you're using it: `File.ReadAllLines(html)`. Read the documentation for `File.ReadAllLines`. What did you *expect* that method to do, and what is it *actually* going to do?

Comment: Well, you've already got a `StreamReader` - so just call `ReadLine()` until it returns null, and add each line you read to a `List<string>`. But before you do that, try to work out how next time you could have worked out what you were doing wrong before asking. (You may still have had to ask how to solve the problem, but it wouldn't include the code that would never work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code below.  There are some lines in html that are commented out so I used a where to skip these lines

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(Form1.patcherBaseURL + "/patcher.ver");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
string html = String.Empty;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data))
{
    html = sr.ReadToEnd();
    var dic = html
        .Split (new[] { '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Where (line => !line.StartsWith("#"))        // Skip commented out lines
        .Select(line => line.Split(new[] { '=' }, 2)) // Beware: some values have spaces
        .ToDictionary(token => token[0].Trim(), token => token[1].Trim());

    string patchVerStrServer = dic["PATCHER_VERSION_STRING_SERVER"];
}
```

Comment: That actually works, i just have to figure out how to send variables from the module to Form1 lol.. Thanks!

Comment: I'm almost certain that your code isn't the problem, but when i try passing it from the module to Form1, it doesn't work and returns an empty string "".. Unless i do a get<function> in the module. But i don't know how to return strings... If you can help with that, i'd be greatly appreciated! I keep looking everywhere.. but can't find a reason why having it as Module.<string> wont work..

Comment: You need to pass variables to a form using the instance of the form that is being displayed.  See my two form project at following posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36251695/c-sharp-reference-two-forms